# Is it possible to set Emule to a private server?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, file-sharing

Is it possible to start a private Emule server in order to share documents in a closed group? Something like Bittorent Sync but with the ability to search in the files of other connected clients and download only files you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for an answer, take a look at http://retroshare.net/
This is exactly :"Emule in a closed group."